# How should I configure AAM in my environment to get rid of this error?

Tags: error, alternate-access-mapping

I am running SP2013 standard. The App server (just single server, no separated WFE or DB) have machinename win-machinename and static ip 192.168.1.104. On the DNS I setup A record "web  192.168.1.104"

Right after the SP2013 installation completed, there are two web applications. One is     `http://win-machinename:12345` as the CA. Another is     `http://win-machinename`. In the AAM I changed     `http://win-machinename` to     `http://web.domain.com` (for all 5 zones)

Since all of our users site within Intranet, I think it is fine and easy setup. All users and me can access by     `http://web.domain.com` as expected. However, in the event log I found following:

Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site     `http://web.domain.com` with the URL     `http://win-machinename`.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL     `http://win-machinename` as an AAM response URL.

The running account for this error is "wss_service" which I setup to run Sharepoint services.

May I know how to get rid of above error and why the error? Thanks.

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed by correct the IIS binding. Orginially I have an IIS entry listen to wildcard hostname on port 80. This entry is linked to `http://web.domain.com` Sharepoint web application.

Some service was visiting `http://win-machinename:80` and land on `http://web.domain.com`  triggered the error. After I amend the IIS entry to bind with hostname "web.domain.com" port 80 no more error occur.